# Sending Email with mailgun in laravel error

Tags: laravel, mailgun

Hello i've been simply trying to send an email in laravel i read the documentation and they made it seem so easy but whenever i try i keep getting error after error, i tried sendgrid didn't work and now i'm trying to use mailgun but i'm having issues with it as well.

This is my code::

```
$data = array();

        Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'John Doe')->subject('This is a demo!');
        });
```

This is the error i get:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (400)

Client error response [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v2/mail.xxxxxxx.com/messages.mime [status code] 400 [reason phrase] BAD REQUEST
```

Mail Config:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'mailgun',

    'host' => 'sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org',

    'port' => 587,

    'from' => array('address' => 'mail@xxxxxx.com', 'name' => 'Xxxxxxxx'),

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    'username' => 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',

    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'pretend' => true,

);
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on your current mail config, and where you're instantiating emails.auth.activate?

Comment: What do you mean by instantiating? I thought that was supposed to be the path to the view.

Comment: I mran just show us more code, things like where your mailgun settings are, where you load in any libs, where you are getting your config settings from.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. First of all, install guzzle package by adding `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"` line inside `composer.json`
2. Update composer using `composer update`
3. Create your account on mailgun from http://www.mailgun.com/. After creating account, kindly note the mail gun subdomain created like `sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org` and API key created like `key-65c33f1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
4. Go to `config/services.php` file and replace

   ```
   'mailgun' => array(
       'domain' => '',
       'secret' => '',
   ),
   ```

   with

   ```
   'mailgun' => array(
       'domain' => 'sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org',
       'secret' => 'key-65c33f1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   ),
   ```

   If you want to create your own sub-domain, you can create and assign to domain (as an alternative)
5. Configure `config/mail.php` like this

   ```
   'driver' => 'mailgun',
   'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
   'port' => 587,
   'from' => array('address' => 'mail@xxxxxx.com', 'name' => 'Xxxxxxxx'),
   'encryption' => 'tls',
   'username' => null,
   'password' => null,
   'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
   'pretend' => false
   ```

Note that you do not need to supply username and password for this. Mailgun will handle this.

Try sending email now. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: hi, where do we get the secret key 'secret' => 'key-65c33f1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to add one possible reason for the error.  I received this error while using sandbox mode when I hadn't set the authorized recipient yet.  When I logged into Mailgun and added the intended recipient to the "Authorized Recipient" list the error went away.

Comment: Hey there.. How do you add an authorized recipient? In MailChimp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and kept getting the following error:
Client error response [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime 404 not found

There isn't much written about this error written online for Laravel 5.1 which I'm using. It turns out that in the config->services the default Laravel 5.1 installation comes with :

`'domain' => env('');`

`'secret' => env('');`

for some reason if you keep your domain and secret wrapped in env as per default installation, the MailGunTransport doesnt pick it up. So just set it to the following:

`domain' =>'yourdomain';`

`'secret' => 'yoursecret';`

Hope this helps since I'm sure i'm not the only one who probably run into this issue.

Comment: I think to get it to work like what you had before you have to also set the domain and secret it in the .env file.

Comment: Thank you, I was having this 404 not found problem too, using Laravel 5.4. The documentation has the example as you suggest, but the actual code still has the `'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'), 'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),` and the `env()` may be overlooked. I decided to set `domain` and `secret` in the env file so this file remains unmodified and only refer to the env file for this stuff.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the secret-key not the public mailgun key in your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as I hadn't activated my mailgun account. Once activated all worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to send mail to the persons in the same domain unless you have added them in the authorised recipient category.
If you add someone to authorised recipient category then he/she would have to approve the request and then only would be able to receive the emails.

Answer (score 0):

I also stucked once in configuring the Mailgun in Laravel 5.1 and what worked for me is the following process. Hope its helps someone:

1) Install guzzle package by adding "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.0" line inside composer.json like this:

```
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"
},
```

2) Update composer using `sudo composer update` in the terminal.

3) Restart Apache.

4) Create the account in http://www.mailgun.com. It will create a `Sub Domain` and `API Key`.

5) Add the `Sub Domain` and `API Key` in the `.env` like this:

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox8...........3b.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-9..................04
```

6) And in the services.php add these line:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

7) Now the mail.php as follows:

```
'driver' => 'mailgun',
'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
'port' =>  587,
'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => null,
'password' => null,
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

I hope this works for you all.