# Mailgun with Laravel

Tags: laravel, mailgun

```
Client error response [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org/messages.mime [status code] 400 [reason phrase] BAD REQUEST
```

I tried anything but this status 400 gets me stuck. What should i do with this. Please help

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the code looks like that's sending the request to mailgun. My guess is that the request is getting sent as null.

Comment: I use default laravel authentication then I just setup mailgun.

Comment: I'm fairly new to laravel, I don't know the file wherein the whole sending request happens.

Comment: So you must have a Mail::to thing going on to get the 400 right? It usually has a view that works with the message. What does the view look like?

Comment: Could you setup proper things in composer file and in `config/services.php` ? May be problem is there..!! Please prefer this answer, may be it helps you:)  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286445/sending-email-with-mailgun-in-laravel-error]

Comment: @RHAMAB: Is it helpful??

Answer (score 0):

Try with only "to" option avoid "cc" & "bcc" and try it. I am also stuck with the same for sending with "cc" & "bcc".

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api", mailgun.api.key));
WebResource webResource = client.resource(mailgun.client.resource);
MultivaluedMapImpl formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("from", xxxxxxxx);
formData.add("to", xxxxxxxx);
formData.add("subject", xxxxxxxx);
formData.add("html", xxxxxxxx);
webResource.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post( ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

Note: Change "xxxxxxxx" with valid values in string format.

Hope this will help you. :)