# Mailgun with Laravel Hooking error

Tags: laravel, mailgun

it took me 6 hours to figure this. I hope anyone of you can actually help me hooking up laravel and mailgun.

I don't know but i had  400 status code error in my terminal whenever i tinker an and send to a particular email

> Client error response [url]
>   https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxx****************.mailgun.org/messages.mime
>   [status code] 400 [reason phrase] BAD REQUEST

This is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:tSyqURI2iJ26tPt7w7L78atftuykcyheipz2VfmPptg=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mypharma
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox******************.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=********************   
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxc9f534073211405983ca9fc9a33b1b85.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-e45bdcaeef418302720dedcbb488269b
```

services.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Stripe, Mailgun, Mandrill, and others. This file provides a sane
    | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
    | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
    'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'sparkpost' => [
    'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
    ],

    'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),

    ],

    ];
```

mail.php

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill",
    |            "ses", "sparkpost", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' =>  env('MAIL_DRIVER'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => 'administrator@mypharma-app.com', 'name' => 'mypharma app'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

I can't seem to find any solution to this. I researched a lot of topics but I think they're outdated. Can someone please give me a detailed tutorial on hooking up mailgun with laravel.

Comment: We use port 587 for our mailgun services. Could that be the issue? Try changing your port to 587

Comment: Can you post your tinker code? Perhaps you missed the "to" field when sending email

Comment: Also your pretend seems to be missing in your mail.php. You need to set 'pretend' => false in your mail.php

Comment: >>> Mail::send('emails.test',
... ['testVar' => 'Just a silly test'],
... function($message) {
...   $message->to('YOUR@EMAIL.com')
...           ->subject('A simple test');
... });

Comment: Can you please just provide me some steps to set up mailgun with laravel. That would help

Comment: Check this post for setup steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29356915/7377984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added your email as authorized recipient. https://mailgun.com/app/testing/recipients?