# Mailgun emails not going out

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4, mailgun

I'm creating a verification email, however the mail isn't going out and I don't receive any errors.

My call to send the email:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    Mail::to($user->email)
        ->queue(new VerifyEmail($user));

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

here's my email build function:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.account.verify_email')
                ->with([
                    'id' => $this->user->id,
                    'firstname' => $this->user->firstname,
                    'token' => $this->user->email_verification_token,
                ]);
}
```

I installed `guzzlehttp/guzzle`

and changed my files:

**ENV (not sure of the port setting)**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox...655.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=Default mailgun sandbox Password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**config/services**

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('sandbox...655.mailgun.org'),
    'secret' => env('key-...'),
],
```

**config/mail**

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

I don't receive any errors, however there are no outgoing mails when I check the mailgun dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your services config file is wrong:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('sandbox...655.mailgun.org'),
    'secret' => env('key-...'),
],
```

You're trying to look up the values from the .env file here. Should reference the keys, not the values. For instance:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAIL_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAIL_SECRET'),
],
```

And then add them to your .env file:

```
MAIL_DOMAIN=sandbox...655.mailgun.org
MAIL_KEY=key-...
```

I'm assuming the rest is correct but I don't know for certain. :)

Comment: aah such an obvious mistake, I also figured out you can't use your env values, since mailgun won't pick it up. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286445/sending-email-with-mailgun-in-laravel-error) so I had to use `'domain' => 'sandbox...655.mailgun.org'` and the same way for secret!